# What is listening at given port?

Tags: linux, networking

Is there a way to determine what program is listening to some port, TCP or UDP, in Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
netstat -lp
```

is the command you want, but you need to be root to see all the data.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't thought about reading `netstat` docs...

Answer (score 2):

ss -tlp

Quicker than netstat.

Comment: nice.. i didnt know about this command..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://www.go2linux.org/which_service_or_program_is_listening_on_port) and [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/security/?p=443).

Answer (score 1):

Already answered, but if it's on a system you don't have a shell on, running `nmap -sV -p <port number> <target>` will often give you the answer. Add `-sU` if scanning a UDP port.

Comment: I know about nmap... anyway, I didn't wrote it in question, so +1.